# Run PHP file as HTML

Tags: php

I have a PHP page that's mostly HTML with a llittle bit of PHP sprinkled in. I want to preview it on my local server (so I can customize the CSS) without taking the time to install a PHP server and establish a connection to a remote database that would require a new network interface and VPN tunnel just to ping. I can accomplish this by simply commenting out the PHP. Short of comments, though, is there another way to tell my computer to ignore the PHP and display the client-side code?

Comment: Wrap it in a comment? `<!-- <?php //code ?>-->`

Comment: without installing a local server the only way is to comment it out, another option is to view the page on your site, copy the source of the page and then edit the css, this wont contain any php code

Comment: @Kiee You can't comment out PHP code with HTML comments, in a PHP interpreted file............

Comment: @ZanderRootman: The file is not interpreted by PHP, as the OP says: "without taking the time to install a PHP server".

Comment: If you have embedded HTML, all you need to do is open it in your local browser. No server needed and your PHP will show up as plain text unless commented out in HTMl like @Kiee said

Comment: @Zander Rootman But if hes running it locally, wouldnt it be ran as just a html file?

Comment: I've been using HTML comments and they work just fine because I'm not running PHP. Those are great suggestions, @Dale !

Comment: @Kiee: it's what the OP is already doing.

Comment: @Kiee She is running it locally, but if the PHP isn't commented out, the page isn't rendered and the full source shows up as text.

Comment: would your code run and handle errors correctly without a database connection?  You could pass the script through the interpreter on the command line if you have it installed and have it spit out the processed *HTML* ***i.e.*** `/path/php -f myFile.php > myFile.html`

Comment: Great idea, @Emissary ! It won't work for pages with sessions and logins, but it'll still work for half of them.